# Updating Metasploit: Most recent modules

Tags: kali-linux, metasploit

Is there a way on kali-linux to update Metasploit via git without msfupdate? msfupdate seems to not get all the most recent modules. In addition, when I clone the most recent repo on Metasploit and write it over the old one, Ruby gives me a lot of trouble trying to rebuild Metasploit.

Answer (score 0):

From the Metasploit "rootFolder", just pull the branch you need: `git pull origin master`.

Answer (score 0):

msfupdate is no longer supported when Metasploit is part of the operating
system. Please use 'apt update; apt install metasploit-framework'